# Render Razor views from string

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, amazon-s3, asp.net-core

I have looked for similar questions but have not managed to build a solution yet.

Basically what I need is to render views from strings in memory.

Example:

```
    public IActionResult Test()
    {
        var model = new MyModel
        {
            Name = "Joe"
        };

        var cshtml = "<h1> Hello @Model.Name </h1>";

        var myView = MyAwesomeEngine.CreateView(cshtml, model);

        return View(myView)
        //or
        return myView
    }
```

Is this possible? I have tried RazorViewEngine inheritance without success, what would be the correct way to render views from string without looking for files in view paths?

I am using aspnetcore 1.1

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: My views are going to be constantly modified by a group of people with access to a AWS bucket with the views, they will be able to add more views (so my application will be listing the bucket for available views) so basically I am going to read the views from the bucket and caching them in memory to avoid lots of S3 requests.

Comment: or would it be easier to have a process syncing the bucket files on my views path?

Comment: Did you try either? I would think that the bottom one would work.

Comment: You could implement an [IFileProvider](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/301/loading-asp-net-core-mvc-views-from-a-database-or-other-location)

Comment: Looks like IFileProvider is worth a try, I will let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Legends](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2581562/legends) suggested using IFileProvider method worked correctly!

Using the example of this [link](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/301/loading-asp-net-core-mvc-views-from-a-database-or-other-location) I was able to do it (without the database)

This was my test IFileInfo implementation:

```
public class MemoryFileInfo : IFileInfo
    {
        private byte[] _testContent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(@"@model TestModel
            <p>@Model.Name</p>");

        private string _viewName;
        public bool Exists { get
            {
                return _viewName.Equals("/Views/Home/TestView.cshtml");
            }
        }

        public MemoryFileInfo(string name)
        {
            _viewName = name;
        }

        public long Length => _testContent.Length;

        public string PhysicalPath => null;

        public string Name => _viewName;

        public DateTimeOffset LastModified => DateTimeOffset.Now;

        public bool IsDirectory => false;

        public Stream CreateReadStream()
        {
            return new MemoryStream(_testContent);
        }
    }
```

This is another great solution [RazorEngine](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine) but is has no support for netcoreapp1.1 yet