# How can I render a Razor view from a string instead of a file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, razor

I am creating views dynamically in dotnet core but would like to use the Razor engine to help with the binding of validation attributes. I know I would need a custom ModelProvider since I will not be able to (easily) use attributes to decorate properties at runtime but the problem seems to be that all of the Razor methods require a static file and not a raw string (containing razor syntax)

(This was being asked here [Render Razor views from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193648/render-razor-views-from-string) in 2017)

I think this might be due to the fact that tag helpers etc. are compiled and therefore need to be in "source files", which would make sense.

I've looked at https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight but this doesn't support tag helpers and basic things like @Html don't seem to work either, perhaps for the reasons stated above.

Does anyone know of an alternative? If I used something like handlebars, not only do I need to duplicate all of the functionality to create jquery validation attributes but if I set ModelState errors on postback and re-render the view, I would also need additional logic to apply the relevant attributes to the correct inputs so that the errors display correctly. This is doable but just quite long and drawn out.